# Get Attendee Data w/ Website Workflow's 3rd Part Next Steps

Tags: eventbrite

I am working w/ the Event Brite API and I have a need that I am trying to figure out the best approach for.  Right now, I have an event that people will be registering for.  At the final step of the registration process, I need to ask them some questions that are specific to my event.  Sadly, these questions are data-driven from my website, so I am unable to use the packaged surveys w/ Event Bright.

In a perfect world, I would use the basic flow detailed in the Website Workflow of the EB documentation, ending upon the "3rd Party Next Steps" step (redirect method).

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/workflows/

Upon landing on that page, I would like to be able to access the order data that we just created in order to update my database and to send emails to each person who purchased a seat.  This email would contain the information needed to kick off the survey portion of my registration process.

Is this possible in the current API?  Does the redirect post any data back to the 3rd party site?  I saw a few SO posts that gave a few keywords that could be included in the redirect URL (is there a comprehensive list?).  If so, is there a way to use that data to look up order information for that order only?

Right now, my only other alternative is to set up a polling service that would pull EB API data, check for new values, and then kick off the process on intervals.  This would be pretty noisy for all parties involved, create delay for my attendees, and I would like to avoid it if possible.  Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the full set of parameters which we support after an attendee places an order:

```
http://yoursite.com/?eid=$event_id&attid=$attendee_id&oid=$order_id
```

It's possible that `order_id` and `attendee_id` would not be a numeric value, in which case it would return a value of "unknown." You'll always have the `event_id` though.

If you want to get order-specific data after redirecting an attendee to your site, you can using the event_list_attendees method, along with the `modified_after` parameter. You'll still have to look through the result set for the new `order_id`, but the result set will be much smaller and easier to navigate. You can get more information here: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_list_attendees/

Comment: Great suggestion on the modified_after.  How does EB handle the date & time for different areas?  Is it a particular time zone, UTC, or GMT?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the order_id in your redirect URL in order to solve this.

When you [define a redirect URL](http://help.eventbrite.com/customer/portal/articles/426236-order-confirmation-customization#redirect), Evenbrite will automatically swap in the order_id value in place of the string "$order_id".

```
http://your3rdpartywebsite.com/welcome_back/?order_id=$order_id
```

or:

```
http://your3rdpartywebsite.com/welcome_back/$order_id/
```

When the user completes their transaction, they will be redirected to your external site, as shown here: /http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/workflows/

When your post-transaction landing page is loaded, grab the order_id from the request URL, and call the [event_list_attendees API method](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_list_attendees/) to find the order information in the response.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response!  That just about covers it, but I have one more question.  Can I supply order ID as a filtering criteria for the API call? For example, http://API-URL.com?id=2&order_id=463

Comment: unfortunately, that type of filtering will need to be done on your end.  Just make a function that accepts an order_id, and then filters the response, returning just the matching order.